# What happens when putting UTF-8 data into a latin1 database column?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I'm getting some data which is encoded in `UTF-8`, which will be Spanish. The database column I need to put it into is currently using the `latin1` charset.

What happens if I put that UTF-8 data into those columns? Will I lose any of the correct data?
Or should I convert the encoding with the php function `mb_convert_encoding`?

Comment: Your question indicates that you already know the answer. "Should I do it the wrong way, or the right way?"

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every possible byte sequence is valid in `latin1`, so you *could* put UTF-8 encoded strings into your column and nothing will complain.  When you extract the data back out of the database, the bytes will be the same as when they went in so provided the client knows those bytes are UTF-8 encoded you will get back your original data.

However, you really shouldn't do it that way: why not change the column data type to UTF-8?

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_column TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought of changing the column charset but was scared of messing up the current data in it. But from what you said, it sounds like all the data will be ok.

Comment: @Brett: MySQL will attempt to convert existing data in your column to the new character set.  Therefore, if you have UTF-8 encoded data in the column you should first convert it to the `binary` character set and *then* to UTF-8.  (If you've already converted to UTF-8, don't worry - convert back to `latin1` then `binary` then `utf8`).